# Can you display an empty value with an array if the value is missing?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have this piece of code.

What it does is it shows the supplier name via email.
The problem is that if the supplier name is empty as some dont need it, i get an error which redirects me to this piece of code.

Is there a way for me to say that if the suppliername is empty, to show as none?? or as a blank space?

```
<?php 
    $array1supplier = get_post_meta($productId, 'fancyincarray', true);
    echo $array1supplier['supplier']; 
?>
```

Comment: Well you want to know if the value is empty. So google: `PHP check empty` and you already got your solution.

Comment: Sure, use [if()](http://php.net/if)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if the array has a key you can use the [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function like so:

```
$array1supplier = get_post_meta($productId, 'fancyincarray', true);
echo (isset($array1supplier['supplier'])) ? $array1supplier['supplier'] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `empty()` function to check if empty or not. 
Code:

```
<?php 
    $array1supplier = get_post_meta($productId, 'fancyincarray', true);
    if(empty($array1supplier['supplier'])) {
    echo "Supplier is empty!"; 
    } else {
    echo $array1supplier['supplier']; 
    }
?>
```

or

You Can also use `isset()` function to check if it is set or not.

Code:

```
<?php 
$array1supplier = get_post_meta($productId, 'fancyincarray', true);
if(isset($array1supplier['supplier'])) {
echo $array1supplier['supplier'];
} else {
echo "Supplier is empty!";
}
?>
```

or

You can just use `if($array1supplier['supplier'] == "")`

Code:

```
<?php 
$array1supplier = get_post_meta($productId, 'fancyincarray', true);
if($array1supplier['supplier'] == "") {
echo "Supplier is empty!"; 
} else {
echo $array1supplier['supplier']; 
}
?>
```

All of them are same, you can choose anything you want

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are expecting an array to be returned from `get_post_meta()`

According to [WP Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/):

> get_post_meta ( int $post_id, string $key = '', bool $single = false )
>
> Retrieve post meta field for a post.
>
> Return: (mixed) Will be an array if $single is false. Will be value of
>   meta data field if $single is true.

So the last parameter should be `false`.

Use `isset()` to determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

Try this:

```
$array1supplier = get_post_meta($productId, 'fancyincarray', false);
echo (isset($array1supplier['supplier'])) ? $array1supplier['supplier'] : "Empty";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
            $array1supplier = get_post_meta($productId, 'fancyincarray', true);
            echo (!empty($array1supplier['supplier']) 
              ? $array1supplier['supplier']
              : '';
?>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code. Describe how and why it addresses the question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, unfortunately did not work for me. I can see the logic though.